# I want to show recently view product in bigcommerce

Tags: e-commerce, bigcommerce

I am new to bigcommerce. How to show recently view products in bigcommerce?
I want to add recent view products and featured products on product page.

Comment: You can use an app to help surface this, otherwise it lives in the account area for the store shopper.

Answer (score 0):

First You should need to correct your questions, that which themes you working on with big commerce, the blueprint or Stencil Framework.
Here is the answer for the simple blueprint theme example classic theme.
open your product.html make sure there will be two files with the name product.html you should be open the file which one have code like below:

```
         <div class="inner">
                %%Panel.WrapperBanner%%
                %%Panel.ProductBreadcrumb%%
                %%Panel.ProductDetails%%
                %%Panel.SimilarProductsByCustomerViews%%
                %%Panel.SideProductRelated%%
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
```

Now change the above code like below:-

```
<div class="inner">
                    %%Panel.WrapperBanner%%
                    %%Panel.ProductBreadcrumb%%
                    %%Panel.ProductDetails%%
                    %%Panel.SimilarProductsByCustomerViews%%
                    %%Panel.SideProductRelated%%
                    %%Panel.HomeFeaturedProducts%%
                    %%Panel.SideProductRecentlyViewed%%
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
```

This two variable will show featured and recently view products on your product page.

```
%%Panel.HomeFeaturedProducts%%
%%Panel.SideProductRecentlyViewed%%
```